# jQuery mobile. Dynamically filling Select menu. Option doesn't display initially

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am having issues with dynamically populating a select menu in jQuery mobile.

When I append the options, the initial value isn't shown and I just get a blank line. The values are there and selectable when clicking on the menu, but it is just the initial view. It works fine when I hardcode the menu into the page. I would assume it is because I initially have an empty dropdown which is showing as it should and when appending, the view doesn't know to update so keeps showing an empty line. Is there anyway I can force the view to update after I have appended? I've tried `.trigger("create")` but this does nothing.

Here is a screen showing what I mean. The "location" dropdown is the one I am having issue with and the "test" one is one I have hard coded to show what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<label for="location" class="select">Location</label>
<select name="location" id="location"></select>
<label for="test" class="select">Test DD</label>
<select name="test" id="test">
  <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
  <option value="test5">Test 5</option>
</select>
```

And here's the JS:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM locations WHERE lDeleted != 1',
  [],
  function(tx,results){
    var len = results.rows.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
      $('#location').append('<option value="'+results.rows.item(i).ID+
        '" class="dropDownBlk">'+results.rows.item(i).lTitle+'</option>');
    }
    $('#location').append('<option value="0">Add new location...</option>')
  },
  errorCB
);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has done the trick:

```
$("#location").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 7):

After:

```
$('#location').append('<option value="0">Add new location...</option>');
```

Try:

```
$("#location").selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you append all options to your menu:

```
$("#location option[value='test1']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

or if you just want the first value selected:

```
$("#location option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: I like the idea. I tried by doing $("#location option:first").attr("selected", "selected"); but this didn't have the desired effect

Comment: it should work, are you sure you are doing it after the options where added to the location?

Comment: I am, yes. I thought this would have worked too. I have found a different solution. Will post in a sec

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. If I remove the jquery mobile reference it does work but as long as I add the referece back the prefilling will gone. Fraser's solution posted above can resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
$(document).on('change', "body", function(){
    $( ".ui-selectmenu" ).selectmenu();
});
```

and if not work trigger body change event manually.

```
$('body').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked for me:

```
$.each(AllTxnDAT_PRV, function(index, item) {

        var DocCode =  item.DocCode;
        var DocName =  item.DocName;        
        htmlDOC += '<option value="' + DocCode + '">' + DocName + '</option>';

    });         

$('#DocType > option').remove();
$('#DocType').append($(htmlDOC));   
$('#DocType').selectmenu();
$('#DocType').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```